# Print an array value only once - but still print rest of array?

Tags: php

been using most of the day to solve my problem - and i am about to give up.

I have an array looking like this:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Henning smaall"
      ["drivernumber"]=>
      string(4) "8830"
      ["period_start"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-20"
      ["period_end"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-31"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["note"]=>
      string(9) "Operation"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Henning smaall"
      ["drivernumber"]=>
      string(4) "8830"
      ["period_start"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-17"
      ["period_end"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-17"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["note"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [2]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Henning smaall"
      ["drivernumber"]=>
      string(4) "8830"
      ["period_start"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-16"
      ["period_end"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-16"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["note"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [3]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Henning smaall"
      ["drivernumber"]=>
      string(4) "8830"
      ["period_start"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-27"
      ["period_end"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-27"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["note"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [4]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Henning smaall"
      ["drivernumber"]=>
      string(4) "8830"
      ["period_start"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-31"
      ["period_end"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-31"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["note"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Henrik Hjersing"
      ["drivernumber"]=>
      string(4) "8850"
      ["period_start"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-10"
      ["period_end"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-24"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["note"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Henrik Hjersing"
      ["drivernumber"]=>
      string(4) "8850"
      ["period_start"]=>
      string(10) "2018-07-18"
      ["period_end"]=>
      string(10) "2018-08-01"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["note"]=>
      string(11) "asdasdasdad"
    }
  }
}
```

The output i am looking for should be something like

```
Henning smaall (8830)
2018-07-20 - 2018-07-31
2018-07-17 - 2018-07-17
2018-07-16 - 2018-07-16
2018-07-27 - 2018-07-27
2018-07-31 - 2018-07-31

Henrik Hjersing (8850)
2018-07-10 - 2018-07-24
2018-07-18 - 2018-08-01
```

For now i am using dummy data and easy php testcode - but i keep getting the name reccuring in the output.

Database function:

```
public function resultsetGroup(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

SQL function:

```
public function getVacations(){
  //$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM vacation ORDER BY user_id, status, period_start');
  $this->db->query('SELECT u.id, u.name, u.drivernumber, v.period_start, v.period_end, v.status, v.note FROM users u, vacation v where u.id = v.user_id');

  $results = $this->db->resultsetGroup();

  return $results;
}
```

This is the php code i've been trying to alter in 500 different ways, and still i cannot get the result i am after - if i do not pdo group by u.id but u.name - it works, but then again, 2 people can have the same name - and that will break my intention.

```
<?php var_dump($data['vacations']); ?>
<?php foreach($data['vacations'] as $key => $vac) : ?>
    <?php echo $key; ?>
    <?php foreach($vac as $va) : ?>
    <?php echo key($vac);?>
    <h1><?php echo $va['name'] ?></h1>
    <?php endforeach ; ?>   
<?php endforeach ; ?>
```

Can you pls help me out? i feel like im running around in cirkles.

Comment: Store name after you echo it and then at beginning of loop check if it is the same as the last one, if so dont echo, if not then echo.

Comment: Also, you need to ORDER BY drivernumber.

Comment: abracadaver: cannot believe i didn't even try that, it worked - guess i was blind to the easy solution. thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here
Try this:

$vacations = array();
foreach($data['vacations'] as $key => $value){
   foreach($value as $index => $person){
      $vacations[$person['drivernumber']] = array();
      $vacations[$person['drivernumber']]['name'] = $person['name'];
      $vacations[$person['drivernumber']]['drivenumber'] = $person['drivenumber'];
      $vacations[$person['drivernumber']]['vacations'] = "";
   }
}// With this, you will have the array $vacations with the drivernumbers as keys without duplicates and initialized the name, drivenumber and vacations string.

foreach($data['vacations'] as $key => $value){
   foreach($value as $index => $person){
       $vacations[$person[drivenumber]]['vacations'] += $person['period_start'] . "-" . $person['period_end'] . " ";
   }
}//This will concatenate all the period_start and period_end of each person in their respective position in the array.

foreach($vacations as $key => $value){
    echo $value['name'] . " " . $value['drivernumber'] . " " . $value['vacations'];
}//Finally.. print in the format that you are requesting.
```

Please try.